# Refactor jQuery dynamic form script for generic use

Tags: jquery

I have a simple form where a user can choose a colour and then a thing from that colour category. The second select input updates based on the first input.

I have a jQuery script which allows me to target the first element based on id and change the next one accordingly when it's id is specified. Now I want to make this into a reusable script so that I can choose ANY select and update the NEXT select accordingly. I can take care of the internal logic (url,GET parameter).

In my jQuery script: get parameter), but I can't figure out how to target the next select element after the one selected (I tried with next() but it didn't work).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var nextSelect = $('#id_colour');
    nextSelect.change(function () {
        function updateChoices() {
            var selected = nextSelect.val();
            if (selected) {
                // this line shown for completeness - will be refactored
                $.getJSON(url, {
                    colour_id: selected
                }, function (data, jqXHR) {
                    var options = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        output = '<option value="' + data[i].id + '"';
                        if (nextSelect.val() == data[i].id) {
                            output += ' selected="selected"';
                        }
                        output += '>' + data[i].name + '</option>';
                        options.push(output);
                    }
                    $('#id_thing').html(options.join(''));
                });
            }
        }
        updateChoices();
        $('#id_thing').change(updateChoices);
    });
});
```

Any help much appreciated.

**EDIT**
Here is the html. So I want that when one  is changed the NEXT  will be targeted. I cannot rely on ids or classes.

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <!-- colour -->
    <div class="form_div">
        <p><label for="colour">Colour:</label></p>
        <p>
            <select name="colour" id="id_colour">
                <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
                <option value="1">Green</option>
                <option value="2">Brown</option>
                <option value="3">Blue</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>  
    <!-- thing -->
    <div class="form_div">
        <p><label for="thing">Thing:</label></p>
        <p>
            <select name="thing" id="id_thing">
                <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
                <option value="1">Branch</option>
                <option value="2">Leaf</option>
                <option value="3">Sky</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div> 

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit Choice" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you post an example on jsfiddle? It might be easier to help seeing it as a whole, not only the JQuery script.

Comment: I added the html - maybe that makes things clearer?

Comment: edited answer to fullfit (as i understand a question) your edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make reusable code (which may be used within other scripts), you can create a [utility function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627326/is-there-any-benefit-to-defining-a-utility-function-directly-on-the-jquery-objec):

Just call nextSelect with three parameters; (1) the first select, (2) the second select which will change according to select1, (3) the url where you do the request.

JQuery (v1.8.2):

```
// Utility function
$.nextSelect = function(selectOne, selectTwo, url) {
    var s1 = $(selectOne);
    s1.on('change', function() {
        var colourID = s1.val();
        if (colourID) {
            $.getJSON(url, {colour_id: colourID}, function(data, jqXHR){
                $(selectTwo + ' option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
                $(selectTwo + ' option[value="' + data[0].id + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
            });
            //Example of what the getJSON might do:
            $(selectTwo + ' option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
            $(selectTwo + ' option[value="' + 1 + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
            //End example. Remove/comment example when going live.
        }
    });        
};
//I have left the url empty for now,
//$.nextSelect('#id_colour', '#id_thing', '');
//If you allowed to at least select the container div:
$mySelectedForm = $('.form_div').first();
$.nextSelect("#" + $mySelectedForm.find('select').attr('id'), "#" + $mySelectedForm.next().find('select').attr('id'), '');
```

The HTML (I just shortened it):

```
<div class="form_div">
    <select name="colour" id="id_colour">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="1">Green</option>
        <option value="2">Brown</option>
        <option value="3">Blue</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form_div">
    <select name="thing" id="id_thing">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="1">Branch</option>
        <option value="2">Leaf</option>
        <option value="3">Sky</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

​
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QMzn4/7/)

If this was not what you were looking for, come with feedback and I will adjust the code.

Cheers!

EDIT:

> so that I can choose ANY select and update the NEXT select accordingly.

Ok, so if I understood correctly you want to be able to select the first 'select' --> meaning you in some form need to hardcore the referencing of an id/class. This doesn't need to be the select itself, it can be a wrapper class. The second select would be automatically selected.

Modified the code and the fiddle to adjust for it.

Comment: Well, this works. However, the arguments are hardcoded. How does `#id_colour` become `this` and `#id_thing` become the next `<select>`?

Comment: Ok, tried to change it to fit your needs. If I misinterpreted something, please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

$(this).next() works for me

http://jsfiddle.net/cWQhg/1/

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
<div class="nextsel">I'm div</div>
<div class="nextsel">I'm div</div>
<div class="nextsel">I'm div</div>
<div class="nextsel">I'm div</div>
<div class="nextsel">I'm div</div>
<div class="nextsel">I'm div</div>
<div class="nextsel">I'm div</div>
</div>
​
```

CSS

```
.nextsel {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;    
  height: 40ps;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nextsel.current {
 background: red;    
}
.nextsel.next {
 background: blue;    
}
```

​
JS

```
var nextsel=$('.nextsel');
nextsel.click(function(e) {
    var t=$(this);
    t.addClass('current');
    t.siblings('.nextsel').removeClass('current');
    nextsel.removeClass('next');
    console.log(t.nextAll('.nextsel').first().addClass('next'));

});
​
```

​

---

with sample from your  question:

http://jsfiddle.net/FU7fZ/

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <!-- colour -->
    <div class="form_div">
        <p><label for="colour">Colour:</label></p>
        <p>
            <select name="colour" id="id_colour">
                <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
                <option value="1">Green</option>
                <option value="2">Brown</option>
                <option value="3">Blue</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>  
    <!-- thing -->
    <div class="form_div">
        <p><label for="thing">Thing:</label></p>
        <p>
            <select name="thing" id="id_thing">
                <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
                <option value="1">Branch</option>
                <option value="2">Leaf</option>
                <option value="3">Sky</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div> 
     <!-- next -->
    <div class="form_div">
        <p><label for="thing">Next:</label></p>
        <p>
            <select name="next" id="id_thing">
                <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
                <option value="1">Tree</option>
                <option value="2">Nut</option>
                <option value="3">Deep</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>
```

js

```
var selector='.form_div select';
var changef=function () {
    var t=$(this);

    var n=t.parents('.form_div').nextAll('.form_div').first().find('select').val(t.val()); 
    if (n.length==0) {
        //it is last ....
        n=t.parents('.form_div').siblings().first().find('select').val(t.val())  ;
    }
    //uncomment to change all in recursive way
      /*
    t.addClass('changed');    
    if (!n.hasClass('changed')) {n.trigger('change');return;}
    $(selector).removeClass('changed');
    */
}
             
             
$(selector).change(changef);​
```